# Lakka Retroarch ignores hdmi mode, and cannot correct it via SSH effectively

Tags: pi-4, lakka

Disclaimer, I am using HDMI => VGA to a 480p CRT, raspberry pi 4b

When I change the config.txt to:

```
#480p
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=4
```

the boot screen looks fine (with the lakka logo)

Then when Retroarch launches it is not synced (it boots in 1080p)

I can do the following to correct it via SSH

```
tvservice -p
(sets display to 480p)
```

Except retroarch looks like this:
[image: works perfectly but it is way off to the right]

When I stop the retroarch service it looks fine again:
[image: just as expected again]

Any advice would be great

Answer (score 0):

Hook it up to a normal HDMI and go to video options and then full screen mode. It will let you select width and height (although you might need to switch to the default menu to get to it, then switch back) I currently have mine set to 640*480 for performance.